# How to get Focus on EditText after checked CheckBox?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-edittext

When user launch app then I don't want to allow user to edit in `EditText`. Now what I want that when user click on `CheckBox` then user able to edit `EditText` but below is my code and when I checked the checkbox it is not giving focus. how can I achieve this ?

```
cbIsGap.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {

                    editText1.setFocusable(true);
                    editText1.setClickable(true);
                    editText2.setClickable(true);
                    editText2.setFocusable(true);


                }else {


                    editText1.setFocusable(false);
                    editText1.setClickable(false);
                    editText2.setFocusable(false);
                    editText2.setClickable(false);

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
editText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText.requestFocus();  add both of these in if checked

Answer (score 0):

try this when checked CheckBox

```
txtMobile.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use EditText.requestFocus();
MethodManager inputManager =    (InputMethodManager)editText.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.showSoftInput(editText, 0);

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience with checkboxes, onClickListener provide reliable results as compared to checkedChangeListener. So I would suggest to use clickListener like this

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(checkbox.isChecked())
    {
    txtConsAcNo.setFocusable(true);
                    txtConsAcNo.setClickable(true);
                    txtMeterSrMo.setClickable(true);
                    txtMobile.setFocusable(true);
    }else{
                    txtConsAcNo.setFocusable(false);
                    txtConsAcNo.setClickable(false);
                    txtMeterSrMo.setFocusable(false);
                    txtMeterSrMo.setClickable(false);
    }
            }
        });
```